# SCDF server returning "Error waiting to get Release from a statemachine" when trying to deploy scdf stream

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, argocd

I am trying to deploy an scdf stream through ArgoCD but the pod is not created and I receive the following error:

```
Error waiting to get Release from a statemachine
```

Any idea what this error is? Where can I look for extra logs?

Comment: Where do you see this error message?

Comment: ArgoCD is creating a Kubernetes Job annotated argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PostSync
and this Job is trying to create pods by sending POST requests to SCDF server. The server returns a 500 status with the error above, thrown as SkipperException.